# Converting Shapenet Meshes to Watertight

Tags: meshlab

I would like to convert ShapeNet meshes to watertight meshes. Meshlab claims to be able to generate watertight meshes (for 3d printing preparations) but even after following tutorials for operations like Duplicate Face / Vertex removal (As meshlab meshes have double sided faces), I have not been able to get the mesh to a state that watertight-requiring operations can run on it.

Is there a tutorial on what can be applied to a mesh to make it watertight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group that presented ShapeNet also presented a paper illustrating how to generated watertight meshes from ShapeNet, see: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.01698

The code is available here: https://github.com/hjwdzh/Manifold
And on the github page you also find preprocessed data for 13 ShapeNet classes.

Comment: They added an improved version of the method here: https://github.com/hjwdzh/ManifoldPlus